# AlertDialog overlaps custom keyboard in android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-alertdialog, ime

I am trying to create a dialog with scrollview, which is shown from key click event of my custom keyboard. Following is the code snippet. The dialog alert overlaps the keyboard. Is there anyway to keep it above the keyboard ?

```
AlertDialog dialog;
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog = builder
                    .setPositiveButton("ok", null)
                    .setView(mView)
                    .create();
            Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = window.getAttributes();
            lp.token = mInputView.getWindowToken();
            lp.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_ATTACHED_DIALOG;
            window.setAttributes(lp);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
            dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **[setSoftInputMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setSoftInputMode(int))**

> Specify an explicit soft input mode to use for the window, as per
>   WindowManager.LayoutParams.softInputMode. Providing anything besides
>   "unspecified" here will override the input mode the window would
>   normally retrieve from its theme.

```
......
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: @Nikki set your manifest section `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Comment: @Amiya that didn't help either.